# Fixed an issue with Jest testing by including `--runInBand` but I'm confused as to why

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have a backend server using Node and Express.js and I'm using Jest as my test framework. I had a problem that I couldn't figure out. Let me share my code first:

`// user.model.test.ts`

```
describe('User model test', () => {
  let connection: Connection;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    connection = await createConnection(ormConfig);
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    connection.close();
  });

  it('should not create a user with the same email', async () => {
    await User.create({
      username: 'bar',
      email: 'foo@gmail.com',
      password: 'password'
    }).save();

    const user2 = User.create({
      username: 'foo',
      email: 'foo@gmail.com',
      password: 'password'
    });

    await expect(user2.save()).rejects.toThrowError();
  });
}
```

As you can see here I'm creating a separate connection from my development database here the hooks are attached to test_db.

I have another test on controllers.

`user.controller.test.ts`

```
describe('Get all users', () => {
  let connection: Connection;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    connection = await createConnection(ormConfig);
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    connection.close();
  });

  it('should return status code 200', async (done) => {
    User.create({
      username: 'test',
      email: 'foobar@gmail.com',
      password: 'password'
    });

    const res = await rekwest.get('/api/v1/users');
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    // console.log(res.st);
    done();
  });

});
```

Same thing what I'm doing here. I'm creating a test and attaching to test_db and expecting a different connection pool.

Now the error on the controller is weird `User table already exists`. And on the model I have an error of `test_db doesn't exists`. Now if I removed the hooks in the controller test the errors goes away but I can't test the controller.

So I found a link on how to test a MongoDB using Jest we have the same idea but I don't have the `runInBand`. So I added it `jest --runInBand` and for some reason, it fixes my errors.  Can someone explain to me what happened? In the Jest documentation basically it's saying that your test will run 50% faster but I don't need that or do I?

Comment: Jest should give you a warning about using `async` and `done`. Just pick one or the other. As for `--runInBand` it could be that if you're manipulating the actual database you have a race condition between the two tests, but when you run them serially, no race condition. If you mocked the db you could probably run them in separate threads without issues.

Comment: @ggorlen ohhhh yea. I just watch a video about jest and the `runInBand` is running test in sequential order. Yea its a race condition for sure. I thought jest already do that automatically seems weird they didnt do that. anyway thank you. Im confused about the `async` and `done` ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use both `async` and `done` in a function. If you use `async`, then you're returning a promise and Jest will know to `await` it automatically and handle failed assertions. No need to call `done`. But if you don't use `async`, then you need to call `done` to tell the runner that the test is done. Pick one or the other (I'd get rid of `done` here).

Comment: oh you mean for the controller test? ive tried removing the`async await` but the res will have an undefined value and if I removed the `done` ill have an error saying that `I need to tell jest that the test has been done` your the second person to call me out on that. the first person I didnt mind because he didnt explain it.

Comment: When you removed `done()`, did you also change the function signature to `async () =>` (no `done` parameter)? If not, then it'll still expect you to call `done`..

Comment: yes. the first time im testing it theres no `done` i didnt know that but since the error is showing and looking for a fixed. I found out about `done` callback. maybe a bug on jest?